# Why does the object that this Proc's variable refers to change?

Tags: ruby, closures, scope

In this Ruby 1.9.2 code:

```
class ExampleClass
  def self.string_expander(str)
    -> do
      p "start of Proc.  str.object_id is #{str.object_id}"
      str *= 2
      p "end of Proc.    str.object_id is #{str.object_id}"
    end
  end
end

string = 'cat'                              # => "cat"
p "string.object_id is #{string.object_id}" # => "string.object_id is 70239371964380"
proc = ExampleClass.string_expander(string) # => #<Proc:0x007fc3c1a32050@(irb):3 (lambda)>
proc.call
                                            # "start of Proc.  str.object_id is 70239371964380"
                                            # "end of Proc.    str.object_id is 70239372015840"
                                            # => "end of Proc. str.object_id is 70239372015840"
```

The first time to `Proc` is called, `str` inside the `Proc` starts off referencing the original object, but then, after the `str *= 2` operation is run, references another object. Why is that? I expected that the original string would have been modified, and the `Proc` would continue to reference it.

Comment: `str *= 2` is assigning a new string to `str` (same as `str = str * 2`) so it gets a new object id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign:

```
str = "abc"
```

`str` gets an object id. If you did this:

```
str[1] = 'd'
```

Then the object id of `str` wouldn't change because you are modifying the existing string.

However, if you do any of these:

```
str = "123"
str = str * 2
str *= 2
```

You are creating/assigning a new string to `str`, so it's object id changes.